# How do I pass a variable in a loop to a remotely executed command?

Tags: shell, ssh

I am trying to write a shell script to remotely power on and off VMs on an esxi server. Since the vmid is not static I have to grep out the hostname and then use awk to get just the first column.  The following command works as expected:

```
ssh 192.168.0.10 'VMID="$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep HPDesktop2  | awk "{print $1}" )"; vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $VMID'
```

What I would like to do is have a list of hostnames in a separate file, loop through those hostnames, and run the command on each hostname. I tried the following:

```
while read ID; do

ssh 192.168.0.10 'VMID="$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep $ID  | awk "{print $1}" )"; vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $VMID'

done <Hostnames
```

It seems to not be passing the variable because I get instruction on the usage of grep and the following error:

> Usage: power.off vmid
>
> Power off the specified virtual machine.
>
> Insufficient arguments.

Comment: observe the output of `sh -c 'echo $1 $2' -- arg1 arg2`. Then apply the same to `ssh host sh -c 'echo $1 $2' -- arg1 arg2`

Comment: Kamil, that is very helpful. Thanks! I am closer but still not there.
I modified my code as such:
`
while read ID; do

ssh 192.168.0.10 sh -c 'VMID="$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep $1  | awk "{print $1}" )"; vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $VMID' -- $ID

done <Hostnames
`

Now I am experiencing two issues $VMID is being set to the hostname (is this because the awk command also uses $1? and it doesn't appear to be looping because I only get one error and it contains the first line of the file but not the second:

Comment: `is this because the awk command also uses $1?` , yes, escape it. `\$1`. Or use `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

example of the problem you're having:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hello="hi"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo '$hello'
$hello
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

the command you're passing as an argument to ssh is in single quotes, so it won't get evaluated on your local machine. That's a problem, since the `ID` variable only exists in the context of your script running on the local machine. Maybe use quotes and us `\"` to escape the quotes inside the quoted string?